# Incompatible types. Found: 'androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper', required: 'androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

[image]
I tried to change the version of Room but nothing helped.
At the same time, it shows strange links in the database.

[image]

I think the problem is in the version of Room,but I don’t know which is more stable.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/text/data/errors. Instead, please use a [code block] for that.

Comment: I am getting the same error, using Room BOM 2.5.2. error in text
```
 Incompatible types. Found: 'androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper', required: 'androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback
```